# Permanent fix to tail: cannot watch `log/development.log': No space left on device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tail, ubuntu-11.10, inotify, sysctl

I've been using **Ubuntu 11.10** for a little over a week now. But after some time I encountered this error(the one in the title) when Im trying to access the log in my RoR project. I found a fix which is by pasting this in the terminal:

> sudo  sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384

The problem is I have to do this again and again everyday. Does anyone know how I can execute this at startup? Or does anyone know any permanent solution? thanks much!!!

Comment: I'd investigate what *else* is using so many watches that `tail` can't get one.

Comment: @ninjalj> sorry im a linux newb, how do i add the code there? just cpy and paste?

Comment: Seriously, the real problem isn't that the sysctl trick is temporary, it's that you need it in the first place.  This shouldn't be happening.  Something on your system is using a lot of inotify watches, which may be a sign of a resource leak somewhere.

Comment: A related question from the Unix/Linux QA: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13751

Comment: @Wyzard: a resource leak? damn, this is a fresh install of ubuntu 11.10, thanks for the link...

Answer (score 13):

I started having this problem with tailing. I think it is because I am also running dropbox on this machine.

My fix is what dropbox suggests:

```
 echo 900000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Comment: this might not be preserved on restart. The @Normz solution however works between restarts as well.

Comment: This happens me to me with Symfony in PHP:

symfony server:start
WARNING Web Server log file cannot be tailed: unable to watch log file: no space left on device
                           
  no space left on device  

Your command resolve this issue too

Answer (score 9):

My issue was fixed. Thanks for everyone who helped!

I placed "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384" in /etc/sysctl.conf